# ASP my simple if statement is not working

Tags: asp-classic

I'm doing a simple a simple html site that I wrote which needed some php, however the server does not have php, only asp. Now I have to learn a bit of asp.

```
<li><a id="main-link" <% If selected = "main" Then Repsonse.Write("class='selected'") End If %> href="/home/">main</a></li>
```

What is wrong with mode code above? I read some tutorials and that what I came up with.

Comment: That looks like classic asp. What error do you get?

Comment: how do I find out? I just saw some files that were already on the server with the .asp file name.

Comment: .asp should be Classic, .aspx is Asp.Net

Comment: I can only see the errors as <p> tags in firebug. "error '800a01a8'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code for `Response.Write`, try this:

```
<li><a id="main-link" <% If selected = "main" Then Response.Write("class='selected'") End If %> href="/home/">main</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo as @derekaug has already pointed out.  However by way of education here is how I would do it.  In an early section of the page where you would put general helper code (and probably where the `selected` variable gets assigned):

```
 Function GetLinkClass(link)
     If link = selected Then
         GetLinkClass = "class=""selected"""
     Else
         GetLinkClass = ""
     End If
 End Function
```

then your links looks like this

```
 <li><a id="main-link" <%=GetLinkClass("main")%> href="/home/">main</a></li>
```

you'll clearly have more than one of these and this would look much tidier.  Its always a good idea to keep the amount of actual code dispersed in HTML elements to the absolute minimum by using functions to contain any logic.